# Classification analysis of a large dataset

Tags: r, machine-learning, large-data

I am trying to run kNN, SVM, and random forest analysis on a dataset of about 9.5 million observations. I am using this code.

```
svm1 <- svm(usertype ~ ., data = CHbikesTrain, 
        method = 'svmLinear',
        trControl = train_control,
        na.action = na.pass)
```

I'm getting told the data is too large. How do I break it into chunks so that the model doesn't run on all the data at once?

Thanks in advance!